# Change Bluetooth name to current IP address on Pi Zero

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, ip

I need the bluetooth name on Pi to change to the current IP of the PI so i can ssh into it because Im constantly changing WIFI and my IP Address always changes.

I have tried FING but sometimes im on a network with over 500 people so a scan takes way too long and burns up my phone ,Ive also tried DATAPLICITY but that only works If the network has internet which isnt always the case.

I am hoping when I power up the PI its bluetooth name changes to the IP i need to ssh into it or if possible to access/edit the wpa_supplicant.conf file via Bluetooth

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't need python for something like this, a simple shell script can do the trick as follows:-

bt-name-ip.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Get current IP address
IP_ADDR=`hostname -I`

# Set new Bluetooth name
hciconfig hci0 name $IP_ADDR

# Check that the Bluetooth name has changed
hciconfig hci0 name
```

You will need to set the script as an executable and maybe give it root permissions in order for it to run the hciconfig command.

I hope this helps.